# Best practice for sizing UIButtons with autolayout in code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar, autolayout

I'm using autolayout in code not IB to add a custom button to a UIToolbar. My question is about best practice. Do I use the following code to add, set and size the button within the toolbar:

(1)

```
//-------------------------------------------------------
// Toobar View
//-------------------------------------------------------
UIToolbar *toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[addButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_normal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_highlighted"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *addNewItemButton = [[UIBarButtonItem new] initWithCustomView:addButton];
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:addNewItemButton] animated:NO];

// Add Views to superview
[superview addSubview:topbarView];
[superview addSubview:_tableView];
[superview addSubview:toolbar];

[toolbar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(10)-[addButton(39)]"
                           options:0
                           metrics:nil
                           views:viewsDictionary]];

[toolbar addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(7)-[addButton(29)]"
                            options:0
                            metrics:nil
                            views:viewsDictionary]];
```

(2) Or do I size the button using different code like this to set the frame size:

```
CGRect buttonFrame = addButton.frame;
buttonFrame.size = CGSizeMake(19, 19);
addButton.frame = buttonFrame;
```

So is Number 1 the recommended way? I have read that settings frames is a plain no in autolayout world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the frame of a view is fine, **if** the view has `translatesAutoresizingMaskToConstraints` set to `YES`. Lots of system views use this setting. This setting is the default for views you create in code. Views loaded from a nib (or storyboard) have it set to `NO` if the nib is set to use auto layout.

Don't try to set constraints between your button and the toolbar.  The toolbar doesn't use constraints to lay out its item views.  (You can see this by poking around the view hierarchy in the debugger.)

Just set `addButton.frame.size` or `addButton.bounds.size` to the size you want the button to have, and set `addNewItemButton.width` to zero.  Setting the item width to zero tells the toolbar to use the button's own size.  The toolbar will center the button vertically.  If you want to add horizontal spacing before the button, insert another `UIBarButtonItem` with a type of `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace`.

Comment: Spot on thanks.I removed any reference to the button from my autolayout code and set the frame size.